# game development, flex project or actionscript project

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am very new to the flash, and I am planning to create a game that links into a social network platform like facebook. I am wondering how are these kind of applications developed in general and which approach is more appropriate.

I will be using some popup windows/buttons for user interface, and sending data back and forth is needed. I am planning to draw the graphics part of the application using Sprites or MovieClips.

I am using flash builder 4.6, and I am trying to decide whether I make the project as a flex project or should I use an actionscript project.

I've read this post, but it didn't help me figure out what is the best choice for me..
[Disadvantages of a Flex project vs an Actionscript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593485/disadvantages-of-a-flex-project-vs-an-actionscript-project)

an off topic question, I tried to add a sprite to the MXML in design mode, I can't see it in design mode, but I can see it when I run the program, is there any way I can visualize that? or is there a way to add custom component to the designer? I think flex will serve me well if I can create visual components like in Macromedia flash and add them in design mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActionScript is much preferred, flex framework is based on ActionScript if your game is based on drawings this is the best method, in this case all the game objects will be light weight. The challenge here will be creating an architecture for your game, you can use most of the OOPS concept to reuse your code and you have to design all the game objects from scratch by using 2D drawing API provided by ActionScript.

For creating costume views you can refer this [link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=intro_3.html)

In case of ActionScript project it wont be having the design views, here you have to visualize your view then code it.

Comment: is it as convenient to create send data using just actionscript? I heard flex framework makes it very easy to deal with data.

Comment: I think AsyncToken is part of the Flex Framework, and I wouldn't want to send data without it or something like it. It wouldn't be difficult to make something that works in a similar way once you know how it works, but the knowing how it works is the trick, unless you have experience in other languages that might give you a frame of reference.

Comment: an addition  to Amy Blankenship comment: Yes, there is one HTTP class in flex this makes things much easier. But the same thing can be achieved in Actionscript using url loaders and url requests classes

Answer (score 1):

To complete the answer by rajesh.adhi: The design view is receiving it's information for display from special metadata in the components written in ActionScript, it also needs what it calls "live preview" - another SWF that mocks the component behavior, tailored specifically for designer to display anything and to interact via scaling, positioning and so on.

Built-in classes don't have that preview, besides, it would be unproductive since Sprite doesn't have anything to display, until you either add children to it, that can be displayed or draw something into its graphics.

Very few people actually bother to supply live preview even if they provide visual components, so, for the most part, that feature of FB isn't useful / doesn't reflect what happens in your application.

Comment: If you created a component based on UIMovieClip, you would probably see it on stage--if it had contents.

Comment: I disagree. Just like if you create a component based on Canvas and put buttons in it and add that to your Application, you'd see those buttons in design View.

Comment: Inspectable determines what happens in the properties panel, not what you see in design view.

And I didn't say MovieClip--I said UIMovieClip.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to use FlashDevelop. 
Start with an Actionscript project.

You can either :

- Create your graphic libraries in Flash CS, givve them classnames in library, export as swc. Import in FlashDevelop.
- Create a flash document with all "pages" of your game in different
  clips lying on the 1st frame of the scene, name the occurences.
  Export as library_en.swf. Load it from your main.swf and get instances of the clips.

The second way is much better if you want to translate items, you create one library per language.

Also take a look at greensock.com, you'll find helpfull classes, loadermax and tweenmax are  perfect.

Comment: I found the refactoring feature is hard to use in FlashDevelop, that is why I switched to the eclipsed based tool which I am more familiar with. The way you suggest to do do graphics work is very helpful, I'll  try if I can get that to work in Flash Builder first. Thanks!